# Как отправить группу фото Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Нужно чтобы от лица бота отправлялось 2+ картинки, причем текст под постом так же должен присутствовать.
Но по дефолту бот отправляет первую картинку, а остальные игнорирует.

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Comment: какой хоть бот-то подразумевается? чтоб вам на нужный [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA) можно было указать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    media = MediaGroup()
    media.attach_photo(photo=InputFile("icon.png"))
    media.attach_photo(photo=InputFile("icon.png"))
    media.attach_photo(photo=InputFile("icon.png"))
    media.attach_photo(photo=InputFile("icon.png"))
    await message.answer_media_group(media=media)
```

Comment: А как отправлять текст вместе с этим сообщением?

Comment: У последнего фото (`attach_photo`) заполните еще и параметр `caption`